# Quarkus native executable build: high memory consumption

Tags: quarkus, docker-multi-stage-build

I'm building a Quarkus native executable with a multi-stage Docker build as described in [Quarkus - Building a Native Executable](https://quarkus.io/guides/building-native-image-guide)

My project just includes the `Hello World`-Example with some added ORM-functionality (so not really a lot of dependencies). The build works fine, but my problem is, that it consumes a lot of memory during build time. That means up to `6 GiB`. Build time is also very long in my opinion (~4-6 minutes in total).

The problem starts when I'm building on our CI/CD-infrastructure. We don't have that much memory there and so the build fails with `Error: Image build request failed with exit status 137`.

Am I doing something wrong or is this just the normal behaviour? Is there a possibility to reduce at least the memory consumption?

Comment: The memory consumption is a result of GraalVM Native Image generation, it's unrelated to Quarkus.

We're aware it usually takes around 4Gb of RAM to perform a native image build, and it usually takes 2-3 minutes, depending on the CPU

Comment: So there is no possibility to limit resources used by GraalVM? Time doesn't really matter in this case, but memory does.

Comment: You can use the -J<flag> to pass the flag to the jvm that is running the image generator so you should be able to limit the memory with something like -Xmx5G (be aware that it may significantly slows down the image generation process).

In quarkus you can set it through additionalBuildArgs configuration option on the maven plugin

Comment: It works, but as you said, it build time is increased. I'm now at 10 minutes with `-Xmx2G`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to Ken and Luca Burgazzoli! So, it is normal for GraalVM to use >4GiB of RAM and to take more than 3 minutes.

One can limit memory consumption by specifiying `-J-Xmx2G` as an `additionalBuildArgs`-param for the `quarkus-maven-plugin`. But this may increase build time.

Answer (score 5):

@ben answer is correct but maybe it is useful to be more precise. You have to edit the `pom.xml` in the `getting-started` dir and edit the `native` `profile` and adding `<additionalBuildArgs>-J-Xmx2G</additionalBuildArgs>` like this:

```
  <profile>
        <id>native</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>native</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
                    <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${quarkus.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>native-image</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <enableHttpUrlHandler>true</enableHttpUrlHandler>
                <additionalBuildArgs>-J-Xmx2G</additionalBuildArgs>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                     ...
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

Answer (score 4):

Now, you can limit memory usage from Quarkus:

In your src/main/resources/application.properties file, just set:

```
quarkus.native.native-image-xmx=2G
```

Or just pass this option to maven:

```
mvn package -Dnative -Dquarkus.native.native-image-xmx=2G
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using gradle, edit the `build.gradle` like this:

```
.
.
.

compileJava {
    options.compilerArgs << '-parameters'
}

buildNative {
   additionalBuildArgs = [
           '-J-Xmx2G'
   ]
}
```

So you can limit the memory usage when building with gradle.

Answer (score 1):

With camel quarkus example using maven, I configured as follows to make it work:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>native</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>native</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <quarkus.package.type>native</quarkus.package.type>
            <quarkus.native.additional-build-args>-J-Xmx5G</quarkus.native.additional-build-args>
        </properties>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                <goal>verify</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Using the option `<quarkus.native.additional-build-args>-J-Xmx5G</quarkus.native.additional-build-args>`